# How to troubleshoot/test Admob mediation with Facebook Audience Network in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

1. We have followed all steps mention [Integrating Facebook Audience Network with Mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook)
2. Added Xamarin.Facebook.AudienceNetwork.Android nuget package Version 5.6.0 to Xamarin Android
3. Downloaded .aar package from [here](https://bintray.com/google/mobile-ads-adapters-android/download_file?file_path=com%2Fgoogle%2Fads%2Fmediation%2Ffacebook%2F5.6.0.0%2Ffacebook-5.6.0.0.aar)
4. Created binding using guidance from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar) & added to Xamarin Android project
5. App is building successfully but no test ad from FAN
6. On Facebook Monétisation Manager - App Status is in review, Integrate the audience network SDK into your app is ticked (Done)
7. I tried to find monetisation test suite package in Xamarin but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You can download mediation test suite arr file [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.ads/mediation-test-suite)
and create binding.

Facebook Audience Network is available on nuget, You do not need to create binding.

I have the same problem as you, if I manage to start, I will speak to you

UPDATE:

I used mediation-test-suite version 1.0.0 because I had problems with the higher version. In addition, I had to install libraries such as:

- FlexboxLayoutXamarinBindingAndroid
- GoogleGson
- Constraint.Layout
- Xamarin.Bindings.Volley

After doing this, the Mediation Test Suite works properly.